# Manjaro Linux - Markdown mode does not work in emacs 24.5

Tags: emacs, manjaro

I have Manjaro Bellatrix (version 15.10) running on my desktop with latest updates as on 2015-11-11. I have installed emacs from the repositories and tried to open a .md file in emacs when I got the following message

```
File mode specification error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "no such file or directory" "markdown-mode.el")
```

It looks like this file is missing in the distribution or this mode is expected to be installed separately. Running `yaourt -Ss markdown` doesn't bring any relevant results. Heading over to the [main-site](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/) for markdown-mode mentions an AUR package that is no longer available.

I need to enable high-lighting and editing support for markdown files. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this excellent site](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs.html) (specifically [this post](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_package_system.html)) I realized the markdown-mode package is now available via Emacs Lisp Package Archive (ELPA).

Performed the below steps to install markdown-mode:

1. Follow the instructions in [this post](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_package_system.html), to configure emacs to connect to the package archive at melpa.org.
2. Run `M-x list-packages` to list all packages avaialble at this archive.
3. Search for markdown (`C-s markdown`) to locate markdown-mode package.
4. Press `i` to mark it for install and then press `x` to perform the installation.

**Note:** You will need a working internet connection of course to connect to the package repository and to download & install the package.

Also avaialble at melpa.org are `markdown-mode+` and `markdown-toc` packages which are valuable complements to the `markdown-mode` package.